# What version of Apache HTTP Client is bundled in Android 1.6?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I want to have a seperate project that runs my server communication code in a normal JVM for the purposes of integration testing.  This code uses these libraries which are build into the Android Framework...

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html

Does anybody know what version of Apache HTTP Client this is supposed to be?  I want to run it without the Android tests which are painfully slow.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The copy of HttpClient in Android does not actually match any of the released versions, as [this mailing list trail](https://web.archive.org/web/20120614203130/http://old.nabble.com/HttpClient-in-Android-td27915358.html) shows. Google seem to have taken an arbitrary snapshot of the development code base and used that.

The closest matches seem to be:

- httpcore-4.0-beta2.jar
- httpclient-4.0-beta1.jar

Seems like a colossal cock-up to me.

Comment: You saved my life, some code I wrote for android was not working with 4.1+... Thank you so much !

Comment: That link is dead for me. If it doesn't work for you do you know how to find it?

Comment: @HeathBorders: I've fixed the link to use archive.org, should be working again.

Answer (score 2):

4.x.  I'm not sure on the minor version code, but the latest versions of httpmime and apache-mime4j work when included in my code alongside the HttpClient included in Android 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear android 1.5 is using apache 4.1.x. mvn dependency:tree shows the following for android 4.0.1.2

```
com.google.android:android:jar:4.0.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:provided
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the exact [source included in the platform](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/apache-http/).