# Android app not recognizing setRedirectStrategy?

Tags: android, httpclient

I am trying to write an android app with apache's httpclient library, and although this code snippet compiles when it is in a actual Java project, it has the error The method setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy(){}) is undefined for the type DefaultHttpClient when I put it into an android app. Does anybody know the reason?

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectStrategy` was introduced with [4.1](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setRedirectStrategy%28org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy%29). Android (apparently) [has a version closer to 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618573/what-version-of-apache-http-client-is-bundled-in-android-1-6).

Comment: In this case, you can't override the system (Android's) implementation, DEX will complain and proguard will probably just ignore those classes (or fail) anyway.

Comment: You can use a `RedirectHandler` though.

Comment: wait how would i use RedirectHandler? httpclient.RedirectHandler?

Comment: Hmm apparently Android doesn't support RedirectHandler (?). See http://blog.kosev.net/2011/01/follow-302-redirects-with.html.