# What version of Apache HttpClient is used in Android 4.2.2 SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, httpclient

What version of Apache HttpClient is used in Android 4.2.2 SDK?  I checked https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ but it does not seem correct, reason being AuthCache class is supposed to be in the Android 4.2.2 SDK if it is using the latest HttpClient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What version of Apache HttpClient is used in Android 4.2.2 SDK?

The same one as has been in every version of Android since the beginning. I think the official number is 4.0-beta-1, or possibly 4.0-beta-2. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818714/115145 for more.

https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ is a refactoring of HttpClient into a new package (`ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib`), to allow for it to exist in your VM at the same time as Android's older version of HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks for the info., sorry I can't vote because of lack of enough reputations at this time.

Comment: Nice answer to many questions brought by Apache HttpClient in Android.