# DefaultHTTPClient in android sends basic auth header in every request after 401 is obtained

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using DefaultHTTPClient in my android Application to connect to the server.
The login URL is protected by basic authentication scheme which involves multiple redirects.

The problem I am facing is that after the 401 is obtained for the first time, the HttpClient is adding the same basic authorization header in the subsequent request due to which there are some side effects in the production environment,.

here is the desired flow:
302 -> 302 > 401>302>302>200 (200 is reported due to the cookies being set by the intermediate responses)

But now  I am getting :
302 > 302 >401 > ***302 >302 >401***

All the requests marked in bold have a Basic authorization header included.

Please let me know how can I resolve this/workaround?

**Edit -1**

On debugging : I found that the authscheme after receiving the first 401 does not get changed due to which the code in RequestTargetAuthentication:

```
 if (authState.getAuthScope() != null || !authScheme.isConnectionBased()) {
            try {
                request.addHeader(authScheme.authenticate(creds, request));
            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                if (this.log.isErrorEnabled()) {
                    this.log.error("Authentication error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

adds the basic auth header in the request. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: What version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: Hi Oleg:
I am using this from android SDK.
I assume this 4.0-beta-1/2 according to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658835/501818]

Comment: Please consider using Apache HttpClient 4.3.5 port for Android instead: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your time.